# How to get mouse coordinates inside a scrollable div or svg from the top left corner?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a scrollable `svg` element (it's width and height are constant but it is actually larger in dimension, and hence gets scrollbars because I have set `overflow: scroll;`).
This `svg` element is inside the `body` with other content. The `body` can also be scrolled around.

Without using JQuery, how do I get the mouse coordinates from the top left corner of the `svg`? By top left, I mean the top left including regions of the `svg` that have been scrolled out. (If I scroll to the very right in my `svg` I should get a high `x` value because the point is horizontally far from the *actual* left of the `svg` regardless of how it is scrolled).

Here is my attempt:

```js
return new Vector(event.pageX - svg.offsetLeft + svg.scrollLeft,
      event.pageY - svg.offsetTop + svg.scrollTop);
```

It doesn't work. `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` are always 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try leaving the SVG at its natural width and height and place it inside a `<div>` that has `{ overflow: scroll }` and do the same computation on the DIV.

That should work in case there are browser quirks with reading the `scrollLeft`/`scrollTop` properties on SVG elements (I haven't tested yet to see if that's the case).

**Update:** you can use `getBoundingClientRect()` like this

```
 var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
 var x = e.clientX + container.scrollLeft - rect.left;
 var y = e.clientY + container.scrollTop - rect.top;
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/aag5fd39/1/

Comment: Tried it. `svg` is huge and `div` is small and fixed. `div` has `overflow: scroll;`. Still doesn't work.